# Filtering Markers Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is my code ..currently I have a  multiple markers  in my map.. I need to filter the result after searching   . I use java Script input tag for entering relevant location..and also use data base  "location" for loading makers into map
Any help would be highly appreciated,

```
 <html>
    <head>
<link href="location.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">

<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100vh}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src=
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1tbIAqN0XqcgTR1-FxYoVTVq6Is6lD98&libraries=places">
</script>
<?php $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "location";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT CellName,Longitude,Latitude  FROM locationdata";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    $table_data;
    $arrayindex=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        $table_data[$arrayindex][0]=$row["CellName"];
        $table_data[$arrayindex][1]=$row["Longitude"];
        $table_data[$arrayindex][2]=$row["Latitude"];
        $arrayindex++;
    }
        //echo $table_data[0][0];

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var locations  = <?php echo json_encode( $table_data ) ?>;
var map
  function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(7.9343623,80.2343398),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),
        myOptions);

    setMarkers(map,locations)

  }

  function setMarkers(map,locations){

      var marker, i

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
 {

 var cellname = locations[i][0]
 var longi = locations[i][1]
 var lat = locations[i][2]
 //var add =  locations[i][3]

 latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map, title: cellname , position: latlngset
        });
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())


        var content = "cell name: " + cellname 

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){
        return function() {
           infowindow.setContent(content);
           infowindow.open(map,marker);
        };
    })(marker,content,infowindow));

  }
  }

  </script>


 </head>
 <body onLoad="initialize()">
  <div id="header">
  <form id="searchForm"> 
     <input type="text" id="searchId"/>
     <script>// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('searchId');
        alert(input);
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            }});</script>
     <button>Go</button>
    </form>
  <ul id="menubar">
        <li> <a href=" 2GLocation.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-hot text-capitalize btn-xs">3G</a></button></li>
        <li> <a href=" location.php"><button>3G</button></a></li>
   </ul>
    <img id ="searchBtn" src=""/></div>
    <div id="content"><div id="default" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div></div>

 <script> document.write("locations");

 </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var markers = []; // declare a array of markers (Global here...)
for ( var index in <yourData>) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position : new google.maps.LatLng(<yourlatlong>),
                    map : <yourmapObject>,
        });
        markers.push(marker);
}
```

the above code will help you push new markers onto the map.... the below code will help you clear your markers from the map....

```
function clearMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        //your condition here...
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    //markers = [];//use this to clear out all the markers.
}
```

Using the combination of the above code you can filter your markers on the map... hope it helps .... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter AFTER retrieving the data results, one way to do that is filtering the data just in the beggining of the for() inside your function setMarkers().

You can just skip the current interation step by using the 'continue' order if the condition you want to filter doesn't match.

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {

var marker, i

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
{
  var cellname = locations[i][0]
  var longi = locations[i][1]
  var lat = locations[i][2]
  // here you can filter the data, for example:
  if (longi > 30.023 && longi < -13.22 ) {
    // if we want to exclude this range:
    continue;
  }
...
```

Comment: Thank you ... but actually I need to  filter  location after given by JavaScript input..and click after GO button of my code need to filter relevant location